# Backbone and jquerymobile error in rendering

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

i'm doing an app with both backbone and jquery mobile disabling jquerymobile routing.
The problem is that when compare the page the header appear,disappear in 3 seconds and definetly re-appears. WHy?

my index html:

```
      <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
   <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum- 
     scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-
   densitydpi=device-dpi" />-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile- 
     1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js">  
    </script>
    <script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.7.min.js"></script>
    <script data-main="js/main.js" src="libs/require/require-1.0.8.js"></script>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
   <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Backbone.js + jQuery Mobile</h1>
    </div>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>


   </body>
   </html>
```

the main with code to disable jquerymobilerouting:

```
     require.config({
paths: {
    jQuery: '../libs/jquery/jquery-loader',
    jQueryMobile: '../libs/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-loader',
    underscore: '../libs/underscore/underscore-loader',
    Backbone: '../libs/backbone/backbone-loader',
    order: '../libs/require/order-1.0.5',
    text: '../libs/require/text-1.0.6',
    async: '../libs/require/async',
    //PhoneGap: '../libs/phonegap/phonegap-loader',
    Handlebars: '../libs/handlebars/Handlebars',
    templates: '../templates'
}
```

});

require(['order!jQuery'], function($) {

```
 // jQueryMobile configuration
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
    $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.pageContainer = $("body");

    // Remove page from DOM when it's being replaced, otherwise the DOM will contain all of them
    $('div[data-role="page"]').on('pagehide', function(event, ui) {
        $(event.currentTarget).remove();
    });
});

// We launch the App
// jQueryMobile is referenced in order to start its initialization
require(['underscore', 'Backbone', 'router', 'jQueryMobile'], function(_, Backbone, AppRouter, jQueryMobile) {



    document.addEventListener("deviceready", run, false);
     run();

    function run() {
```

},

```
        app = new AppRouter();
        Backbone.history.start();

    }
})
```

});